# How can I export a closed workbook sheet to a .CSV file?

Tags: vba, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a set of vba functions that should allow the user to export several sheets from a xls or xlsx file and export them all to different file formats depending on the name of the sheets. It's a very specific procedure using older files.

Some of the sheets in the chosen file should be treated as raw data, and I want to export them as a .CSV file without making any change in the data. If it helps, I don't even need to "see" the data to make IFs or other logical treatments.

I already have a function to get data from a specific cell in a specific sheet from the closed file, but I can't figure out how to get all the data from the sheet without iterating through all the billions of cells that are mostly empty just to check if there is data in the Cell(23785;GP).

Here is the function I already have, which might help understanding the expected behavior.

```
Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _
    ByVal WBName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
    Dim arg As String
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    If Dir(wbPath & "\" & WBName) = "" Then Exit Function
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & WBName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

It is necessary that the other workbook is still closed at the end, and that no changes whatsoever are made to the current one. At the very least, all changes made should be undone so that after choosing the file, the user will only see my confirmation messages and the newly created files on his computer, with no visible difference in his Excel. Since this will be used by people who are neither programmers nor very tech savvy, so any messing up with their current workbook that they could be using for something at the same time will earn us some complaints.

Comment: Look at using SQL via ADO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this really doesn't help much. I've never used vba or excel a lot before, so telling me to "use SQL via ADO" only tells me that there is a way to read the file as if it was a database. I have no idea how, and i also have to export to csv after

Comment: Read on and it will help, this isn't a code writing service.  If there isn't details on how to save a file as CSV I'd be shocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Sub takes a file string and the sheet name as arguments to create a .CSV file with the extension .csv appended to its previous name, sheet name and extension.

```
Private Sub export_file_to_csv(src_path, sheet_name)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set src_workbook = Workbooks.Open(src_path, , True)
    src_workbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Activate

    dst_path = src_path & " - " & sheet_name & ".csv"
    src_workbook.SaveAs Filename:=dst_path, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    src_workbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

You can then call it as many times as needed in another sub.

```
Sub main_sub()
    export_file_to_csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\maps.xlsx", "Europe"
    export_file_to_csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\maps.xlsx", "Asia"
    export_file_to_csv "C:\Users\username\Documents\budget.xls", "Sheet1"
End Sub
```

Just put this code in another workbook, edit the paths and sheet names of the files that will be exported to CSV and run  the main_sub, which should appear on the macro menu. The original files will be kept untouched, as they were open read-only.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very close to what I was looking for. It is a huge step in the right direction. The only problem is that I can't run this on the first sheet only. I have to be able to give the name of a sheet and make it run on that one, since the files will contain about a dozen different sheets in no particular order, and only 3-4 of those will need to be converted to .CSV. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Edited in the answer. Now, you can pass the file path and sheet name to the Sub, so Excel knows which sheet to export for each file. Each generated CSV file will have the selected sheet name in its name.

Comment: Thank you very much! I Accepted the answer, since it does what I needed, but there is a little problem.
Special characters like "é" are replaced by commas, which messes up their lines. It looks like an encoding issue.
Also, the CSV generated are bigger than needed. For example, in one of my sheets, all of the data appears before Column J, no column after I contains any data or fomatting. The generated CSV has thr right number of lines but each line has hundreds of trailing commas with no data in between. The data i need is all there, but the csv is unecessarily large because of that.

Comment: About the changed characters, what is the chosen language for your windows/office installation? Well, the exceding commas are because there are some rows in Excel that has more data than others... yes, this is an issue. Do your CSVs have empty cells other than those last ones? Maybe we can figure out how to solve this last problem.

Comment: The OP is talking about extra columns NOT inconsistent column counts. Excel has a tendency to expand its understanding of the Used Range of cells (both rows and columns) over time usually either due to border formatting or because data/formatting has been deleted. Sometimes in Excel I completely delete rows and columns on the outside of my data that Excel might be including in the Used Range definition. Doing a column delete programmatically before the save may be the quickest fix for the OP's concerns: `Columns("J:IV").EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: Mark is right. The UsedRange is a rectangle. I forgot it completely. But now, I remembered a tip: if you want to eliminate extra columns manually, move the horizontal scrollbar to the right (it then goes to the last column Excel recognizes as having data, a.k.a. UsedRange) and make a selection containing all columns from this column to the last seemingly empty column adjacent to your data, then delete them. If all the sheets have the same column counting (which I don't know if it is the case), then it is possible to delete the same columns for each sheet programatically.

Comment: There are ways programmatically to determine the end of your data such as (mostly from memory...): `Cells(1,Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlLeft)` or `i = 1    While Len(Cells(1,i).Value) <> 0     i = i + 1    Wend`. I do recommend if you start running commands like this to create a `Worksheet` object and not rely on the `ActiveSheet` being what you expect it to be.

Comment: I am using a work computer running Windows 7 Entreprise SP 1 Installed in French.

Comment: As for the extra commas, the sheets have wildly varying sizes, some can stop after 8 columns, while some others can have more than 100­. I decided to keep the extra commas, and to remove them in the C# code where we use those CSV files, since I understand C# way better. The users shouldn't ever need to open or edit the CSV anyway, they are just using the tool to convert the old data format to CSV, then sending the CSV over in our web app so we can put it in the new Oracle Database, so it doesn't matter when the commas are removed, as long as they don't get into the final database insert.

Comment: I found a more comprehensive documentation and it points out the existence of a FileFormat:=xlCSV. I tested and it exported properly some non-ascii characters. Try this one. Also, edited in the answer.

Comment: @EduardoPoço I also found the const xlCSVWindows, why also worked for my special chars. Not sure what the difference between the two is, but my issue is entirely solved now. Thank you very much again :)